# Can I store ether and ERC-20 tokens in one contract?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ether, openzeppelin

I am trying to create a contract to store ether and two ERC-20 tokens. People will transfer ether and the other two ERC-20 tokens to this contract and when the time comes, the owner of this contract will transfer these ether and ERC-20 tokens back to them. I don't know how to make this contract.

Currently, I can make an ERC-20 token contract and it can only store the ether and this ERC-20 token itself like below.

Suppose this contract can store 3 kinds of tokens. When people transfer these tokens to the contract, how the contract itself knows which token was sent?

```
contract WalkDogToken is ERC20, ERC20Burnable, Ownable {
    constructor() ERC20("WalkDogToken", "WDT") {}

    function mint(address to, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(to, amount);
    }

    function decimals() public view virtual override returns (uint8) {
        return 8;
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose this contract can store 3 kinds of tokens. When people transfer these tokens to the contract, how the contract itself knows which token was sent?

Tokens are transferred using `IERC20(address).transferFrom()`. Your contract differs between different ERC-20 tokens by their smart contract address.